# Sorting and filtering map output in golang - okta api

Tags: go, okta, okta-api

I am interacting with Okta API via the go sdk. I am new to golang and able to get data back but in a format that I am not sure what to do with.

```
func main() {
    client, _ := okta.NewClient(context.Background(), okta.WithOrgUrl({URL}), okta.WithToken({TOKEN}))
    filter := query.NewQueryParams(query.WithFilter("status eq \"ACTIVE\""))
    users, resp, err := client.User.ListUsers(filter)
    fmt.Println(resp, err)
    for _, user := range users {
        fmt.Println(user.Profile)
    }
}
```

returns: PII redacted**

```
&{0xc000106480} <nil>
&map[email:{email} firstName:{FN} lastName:{LN} login:{login} mobilePhone:<nil> secondEmail:<nil> sshUserName:{ssh}
next user
next user
so on
so on
```

My question is how can I filter the output to only certain fields and do some sorting or filtering. I was kind of expecting the output to be in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide some struct fields from json output please follow the rule below:

```
type User struct {
  ID int `json:"id"`
  Username string `json:"username"`
  MobilePhone string `json:"-"`
}
```

You must use `-` character to hide struct fields. I recommend you read about Golang tags.
https://medium.com/golangspec/tags-in-golang-3e5db0b8ef3e

Answer (score 1):

You need to marshal the response objects into a json object which you can pretty print a string representation of. Try this:

```
import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "github.com/okta/okta-sdk-golang/v2/okta"
    "github.com/okta/okta-sdk-golang/v2/okta/query"
)

var b []byte
var err error
filter := query.NewQueryParams(query.WithFilter("status eq \"ACTIVE\""))
ctx, client, err := okta.NewClient(context.Background(), okta.WithOrgUrl({URL}), okta.WithToken({TOKEN}))
users, resp, err := client.User.ListUsers(ctx, filter)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err.Error())
} else {
    log.Println(resp.Status)
    if users != nil {
        b, err = json.MarshalIndent(users, "", " ")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```